# RESTful API - Designing sub-resources

Tags: rest, restful-url

I am designing a RESTful API and I came up with a problem related to sub-resources.

I see other APIs using full URL to operate over sub-resources. Take the example where `Company has Departments` and `Department has Employees`.

In the beginning I though about implementing all possible URLs. Resulting on the following:

**Approach A**

```
01. ### COMPANY URLS ###
02. DELETE /companies/{companyId}
03. GET    /companies/{companyId}
04. POST   /companies
05. PUT    /companies/{companyId}
06. 
07. ### DEPARTMENT URLS ###
08. DELETE /companies/{companyId}/departments/{departmentId}
09. GET    /companies/{companyId}/departments/{departmentId}
10. POST   /companies/{companyId}/departments
11. PUT    /companies/{companyId}/departments/{departmentId}
12. DELETE /departments/{departmentId}
13. GET    /departments/{departmentId}
14. PUT    /departments/{departmentId}
15. 
16. ### EMPLOYEE URLS ###
17. DELETE /companies/{companyId}/departments/{departmentId}/employees/{employeeId}
18. GET    /companies/{companyId}/departments/{departmentId}/employees/{employeeId}
19. POST   /companies/{companyId}/departments/{departmentId}/employees
20. PUT    /companies/{companyId}/departments/{departmentId}/employees/{employeeId}
21. DELETE /departments/{departmentId}/employees/{employeeId}
22. GET    /departments/{departmentId}/employees/{employeeId}
23. POST   /departments/{departmentId}/employees
24. PUT    /departments/{departmentId}/employees/{employeeId}
25. DELETE /employees/{employeeId}
26. GET    /employees/{employeeId}
27. PUT    /employees/{employeeId}
```

As you can see, there are many URLs which do the same thing. Example: 08 is duplicated of 12; 09 is duplicated of 13; 17 is duplicated of 21 and 25...

I want to remove the duplication but keep consistency. So, re-designed the API with a principle in mind `sup-resources are fine but sub-sub-resources are not`. Which resulted on the following:

**Approach B**

```
01. ### COMPANY URLS ###
02. DELETE /companies/{companyId}
03. GET    /companies/{companyId}
04. POST   /companies
05. PUT    /companies/{companyId}
06. 
07. ### DEPARTMENT URLS ###
08. DELETE /departments/{departmentId}
09. GET    /departments/{departmentId}
10. GET    /companies/{companyId}/departments
11. POST   /companies/{companyId}/departments
12. PUT    /departments/{departmentId}
13. 
14. ### EMPLOYEE URLS ###
15. DELETE /employees/{employeeId}
16. GET    /employees/{employeeId}
17. GET    /departments/{departmentId}/employees
18. POST   /departments/{departmentId}/employees
19. PUT    /employees/{employeeId}
```

**My Questions**

Q1. Is *Approach B* considered RESTful? (I am assuming yes)

Q2. Are there pitfalls *Approach B* I should consider, assuming that documentation is also provided?

Bonus points if you point to other APIs following *Approach B*.

**EDIT**

`Elad Tabak` presented good insights.

I fond some API using *Approach B*:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Comment: That's a tad too broad, Q3 and 4 basically invite to dump the book on webservice design. You're supposed to ask one question, not a questionnaire. Your core question seems to be Q1 + Q2 combined.

Comment: Thanks Gimby, agree, it is very broad and I care about Q1 and Q2 the most.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both approaches can be considered RESTful, provided you do not break the REST constraints defined in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Roy Thomas Fielding's dissertation:

- [Client-server](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_2)
- [Stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)
- [Cache](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4)
- [Uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)
- [Layered system](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_6)
- [Code-on-demand](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_7)

I cannot see major pitfalls in both approaches, but I would prefer the *Approach B* over the *Approach A*: the URLs are shorter, easier to remember and not many parameters are required.

---

<sup>**Bonus points:** [Spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/) and [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference) APIs follow this approach. For sure there are other APIs, but these are the ones that came up to my mind.</sup>

Comment: Actually none of the URIs are RESTful per se! Its the content they returned that meets the RESTful constraints or not. REST has nothing to do with a clean URI design but more with decoupling clients from server APIs and thus the client should use URIs returned with responses to perform further actions on its current state. Don't know why everyone is confusing URI design automatically with RESTful approach. In addition to that Fielding clarified some of the constraints a RESTful API has to follow further in his [blog post](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)

Answer (score 9):

The design approach raises a few questions you need to consider when choosing between the two:

***Existence dependency***

In **A**, it's very intuitive, that when you DELETE a company, you also deleting all it's sub resources - departments and employees.
In **B**, the API user needs to think a moment about such action - do I need to invoke delete on all employees, or is it enough to delete the company? of course, this can be documented, but still, it's not straight-forward.

**A** have an advantage here, becuase it's very clear - when deleting a resouce, you delete all it's sub resources.

***Operation endpoint***

Another question it raises - how do I update an entity? from which end-point?

If I want to delete an employee, is it enough to update the company with a new set of employees? or must I DELETE the employee?

Or say I want to change employee from one company to another. In **B**, theoretically I can update employee with company field, and be done with it. In **A** there's no such way...

**A** have an advantage where it's very straight-forward how to do an action - CRUD on the entity URL. **B** makes the API user stop and wonder which action he can do on which URL.

But at the same time, **B** have an advantage that changing the "parenting" of an entity is easier (in cases where it's relevant).

***Validation***

In **A**, you must validate the URL arguments match, as user can provide employee id with the wrong company or department. 
In **B** there's no such problem.

Answer (score 7):

1. REST says nothing about URL design. Any URL scheme you come up with is RESTful. You should ask if it's good design. And yes, the second approach is highly preferable to the first. The first is a ton of noise for clients and a huge maintenance issue for the owner. It also limits future flexibility.
2. There are no significant pitfalls that I'm aware of, as long you clearly document how to use the endpoints. For instance, it's typical for the nested endpoints to only return associated elements, and that DELETEing a nested element will only delete the association, and not delete the element itself. That kind of behaviour needs to be documented one way or the other.

Bonus points: asking for external resources is out of scope.

Comment: And to further to this, there's no such thing as a 'sub-resource'

Answer (score 5):

So this might sound a bit mad, but there is no such thing as a 'subresource' in HTTP/REST.

In your domain model, a department can't exist without a company.

Now in your API you expose a json representation of a company at `/companies/{companyId}` and a json representation of a department at `/companies/{companyId}/departments/{departmentId}`.

Those are both 'resources'. A resource, in HTTP/REST terminology, just means a thing that a URL points to. So it's the 'json representation of a company' not the company itself.

URL design is itself a bit of a dead-end alley in itself - URLs themselves can look like ANYTHING, it doesn't matter if they are readable or not. Developers make requests, picking the URLs depending on the operation names from documentation*. Trying to add meaning to the URLs themselves gets tricky quickly, and actually can add confusion as time goes on.

Better to spend time on the documentation, rather than trying to let people infer things about the domain behaviour.

*or hypermedia (e.g. https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren)